# APC gets filled with junk

Tags: php, apc

I have been using APC to store user cache for a website for sotime time now.
Last week i noticed that something was wrong with the APC memory , it was getting filled up very fast.

Usually the user cache was similar with the total APC cache.
Now the APC memory cache gets filled up with i dont know what and it fills up the memory in 1-2 minutes. ( 10 GB ) . Before it was taking a day or more to fill up the memory with my apc_store information.

I have upgraded to the lastest APC verstion and its still the same.
How can i see what in the APC memory thats filling up the space so fast ?
Its not the file cache and not the user cache so i dont know whats in there.

See a screenshot : http://drp.io/TV

The same configuration was working fine on this server a week ago, and i have another server that works fine with the same settings.
What could be the cause of the apc malfunction ?

Comment: 7.3GB free isn't that close to full; but have you looked at the tabs on the top of that screen? Those cache entries tabs show you what is using your APC cache memory

Comment: checked user cache entries?

Comment: it shows 7.3 free because thats when i made the screenshot, it gets filled up to full in 1-2 minutes. there is nothing suspiction in user cache entries or system cache entries. it dosent show whats the rest of the memory used for - http://drp.io/wall/bF

Comment: and when it gets full , it gets stuck like that, and it dosent reset to 0. before it was fuslhing the memory (user cache entries ) and starting from 0, but now it just remains full. - pic: http://drp.io/TZ

Comment: i have found the problem. there was an error in a php file on the website, and i guess it was messing up with the APC.